# How can i get Nivo.slider controls to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I recently moved my website to a new web host and noticed that the nivo.slider nav's are not working correctly. Rather than let the user cycle through the images in the slider, it sends the user to another one of my pages. This only happens in browsers other than IE. Not sure why it is doing this Below is my JS code for the slider. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. My code is actually 60,000 characters too long to be posts, so I have stuck it in my Dropbox. Link is below. Thank you!

Javascript: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbpvihwi8fer4fs/jquery.nivo.slider.js?dl=0